# frequency response of a signal in which two signal added in

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

Here goes the problem I faced:

```
Sig1= A*sin(w*n)
Sig2= B*sin(w*n+phi)
```

Length of both signal is `L`.

Then, I put them in `F(1:2:2*L)=Sig1` and `F(2:2:2*L)=Sig2`.

Now we know what would be the frequency response of `Sig1` and `Sig2` but is there any way we can find frequency response of `F`? FFT of sinusoid is the delta function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask for should rather be called a frequency spectrum or Fourier transform of the resulting signal. The term frequency response is reserved for linear time invariant systems.

Anyway, the answer to your question can be found using the z-transform of the signals involved. First let's expand the two source signals into a series of unit delays:

$$S_1(z) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k z^k$$
$$S_2(z) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} b_k z^k$$

Your combined signal can be written as

$$F(z) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k z^{2k} + \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} b_k z^{2k+1}$$

and we can plug in $z=\exp(i\omega)$ to get the Fourier transform:

$$F(\omega) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k \exp(ki2\omega)+\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} b_k \exp(ki2\omega)\exp(i\omega)$$

Using the Fourier transforms from the z-transforms above we can see that this actually equals:

$$F(\omega) = S_1(2\omega) + S_2(2\omega)\exp(i\omega)$$

You can interpret this result as the additive combination of the two original signal spectra, each scaled in frequency direction by $1/2$ and one phase shifted proportionally to $\omega$.

Since your original signals are of finite length, your initial spectra are *sinc*-shaped, centered at the same frequency and with a constant phase shift. I'll leave working out the details to you.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my answer, but the stretching of the spectrum comes with aliasing! The negative frequency content of the original signal will be moved to the high band of the new signal.

Comment: Its fine, i got the answer, but the problem is amplitude of the F_analytical and F_numerical is different. Here goes the code for matlab:

Comment: Its fine, i got the answer, but the problem is amplitude of the F_analytical and F_numerical is different. Here goes the code for matlab: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RgyXRgb2zLmjcGdQDJ6mVwXlh6lj0EZXSsH6fBcFLfk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your code contains a few errors. The $\omega$ I use above is normalised angular frequency. It ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. Also you can't replace the argument $2\omega$ with a doubled index into the fft output array, because $\omega=0$ is at index=1. That's what I have spotted at a quick glance. There's probably more.